# limit and pagination not working in expression engine exp:query

Tags: expressionengine

What is wrong in this code that is not allowing me to show only two records along with pagination any help highly appreciated?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="article" status="open" orderby="date" sort="desc" 
 search:entry_id="{embed:entry_ids}"  dynamic="off"  limit="1" paginate="bottom"}

        {exp:query  limit="1" sql="select count(*) as recordcount  from exp_channel_data a where entry_id IN ({embed:entry_ids}) AND channel_id=8"}
             <b> {recordcount} </b> articles found for:<b> {embed:author_name} </b>
        {/exp:query}
        <br />

        {exp:query limit="2" sql="Select B.field_id_29 as article_bodysubtitle,B.field_id_27 as bodytext, B.field_id_88 as iss_rel_id, D.title as articletitle, D.url_title as ut from exp_channel_data as B INNER JOIN exp_channel_titles D ON B.entry_id=D.entry_id where B.channel_id=8 AND B.entry_id IN({embed:entry_ids})"}
            <br />
            <strong><a href="{path='article/index/{ut}'}">{articletitle}</a></strong>:
            {exp:trunchtml chars="250" inline="..."}
              {bodytext}
               <br />                        
           {/exp:trunchtml}
           <br />

          {embed="backissues/embed_iss" iss_rel_id="{iss_rel_id}"}
          <br /><br />
{paginate}
<p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
{/paginate}

  {/exp:query}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{exp:query  limit="2" paginate="bottom"  sql="Select B.field_id_29 as article_bodysubtitle,B.field_id_27 as bodytext, B.field_id_88 as iss_rel_id, D.title as articletitle, D.url_title as ut
      from exp_channel_data as B
      INNER JOIN exp_channel_titles D ON B.entry_id=D.entry_id 
      where B.channel_id=8 
      AND B.entry_id IN({embed:entry_ids})"}

      {paginate}
         <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
      {/paginate}

  {exp:channel:entries channel="article" status="open" orderby="date" sort="desc" 
    search:entry_id="{embed:entry_ids}"  dynamic="off" limit="1" }

    <strong><a href="{path='article/index/{ut}'}">{articletitle}</a></strong>:
        {exp:trunchtml chars="250" inline="..."}
          {bodytext}
           <br />
        {/exp:trunchtml}
       <br />
      {embed="backissues/embed_iss" iss_rel_id="{iss_rel_id}"}
      <br /><br />

  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:query}
```

Comment: The problem was with the way ee parse. I took the sql part from inside the channel and added before opening the channel entries and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer-most channel entries query is restricting the data set to return only one result.

Try changing the [limit parameter](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#limit):

```
{exp:channel:entries ... limit="2" paginate="bottom"}
```

When using [pagination](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/pagination_page.html), the limit parameter determines the number of entries shown per page.

Comment: Thanks rjb. I cannot make it limit="2" because search:entry_id="{embed:entry_ids} returns some value that i need to display by doing limit="1" only. The problem is if i use regular select statement  my limit on exp:query works,but some how my above sql query with joins does not take limit="2" on exp:query.